# Python: Using Fabric, does not continue to next function in main()

Tags: python, linux, roles, fabric

I have a Python 2.7 Script that uses fabric and it uses a hostfile that has 4 hosts on it. I am having issues with it exiting after the second function is ran. Once it hits the "except" in checkHostFile it quits and does not follow the main() and go to the installedChoice where it asks user for a raw_input. I also ran the script so that it does not hit the "except" in checkHostFile and just does "try" but it will then just hang after running on the last host. Anyone know how I could rewrite it so it continues and does not exit or hang after finishing the checkHostFile()??

I run the script by running python "filename" and it will run the main() function.

Note: I have tried running it also with "pass" in the "except" in checkHostFile function and it still exits.

```
from fabric.api import *
from getpass import getpass
import os
import sys
import tsmFunctions
import logging
import traceback

env.hosts = open('hosts_file', 'r').readlines()

env.roledefs = {
    'localhost': ['localhost'],
}

with open("./original_hostlist") as f:
    env.roledefs['installhosts'] = f.readlines()

def main():
    print 67 * "-"
    original_hostlist = raw_input('Do you want to proceed? [yes/no]: ')
    print 67 * "-"
    if original_hostlist == 'yes':
        execute(removeFiles)
        execute(checkHostFile)
        installedChoice = raw_input('Is this a new install, uninstall or an     upgrade? [install/uninstall/upgrade](or enter exit to quit): ')
        start(installedChoice)
    elif original_hostlist == 'no':
        print "Goodbye!"

@roles('localhost') 
def removeFiles():

    with settings(warn_only=True):
        with hide ('running','output','stderr','stdout','aborts','everything'):
            local('rm host_file_bad')
            local('rm hosts_file')

@roles('installhosts')  
@task
@serial
def checkHostFile():

    with settings(warn_only=True):
        response = run('uname -r | grep -c \"el\"')
        if response == '1':

            f = open('hosts_file', 'a')
            f.write(env.host + "\n")  
            f.close()  

        else:
            f = open('host_file_bad', 'a')
            f.write(sys.stderr + "\n")  
            f.close()  

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Update: i have modified function checkHostFile() to use if and else: The script is going to the next function if it only hits the if in checkHostFile. But it is still failing if it goes to else (it goes to else if the host is unreachable and cannot do the fabric run command).

```
MacBook-Pro-2:$ python pythonfile.py

[localhost] Executing task 'removeFiles'

Fatal error: Name lookup failed for fake.apple.com

Underlying exception:
    nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Aborting.
```

Comment: What kind of error are you looking to catch in the try block? An error thrown by the fabric run call or from opening the files?

Comment: The `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause is not indented correctly in the code here. Is it correct in your actual code?

Comment: From the output you provided it's failing before it ever gets to checkHostFile. It's actually failing in removeFiles. Additionally you have errors in your checkHostsFile method. In the else case you should have: `f.write(response.stderr + "\n")` instead of `f.write(sys.stderr + "\n")`. I think it would be beneficial for you to go read the fabric documentation a bit more.